# fstream skips the first character

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to read first 121 bytes from a text file onto a structure.

Here is my code.

```
#include <fstream.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main()
{
    struct 
    {
        char map[121];
    } map_data;

    struct stat results;

    fstream myfile("input.txt", ios::in);

    myfile.read((char *)&map_data,121);

    if(!myfile)
    {
           cout<<"Unable to open the file";
    }
    if(!myfile.read((char *)&map_data,121))
    {
       cout<<"Second error occurred";
    }

    myfile.close();
    cout<<"\n Here are the read contents of size "<<sizeof(map_data)<<"\n";



    fstream outfile("output.txt", ios::out);
    for(int i=0;i<121;i++)
    {
        cout<<map_data.map[i]<<" ";
    }
    outfile.write((char *)&map_data,121);


    outfile.close();
    stat("input.txt",&results);
    cout<<"\n Size of input.txt "<<results.st_size;

    stat("output.txt",&results);
    cout<<"\n Size of output.txt "<<results.st_size;

    getch();

}
```

The problem is that the above code skips the first character of the file i.e the h of the hello. Its cout and the output.txt file both show this thing.

Can somebody guide me how to solve this?

Comment: actually i am using it for a project someone wrote back almost 10 years ago. I didn't want to port it to the new one.

Comment: Please do not paste such a horrible code style anymore in here. I tried to edit... it had a terrible indent style, maybe the end result of copy paste...

Comment: @Laszlo Papp I indented each line by four spaces as told to get it shown as code. What else was the requirement?

Comment: Why are you reading same file twice ? It works for me with Mingw.
(after changing the headers and few statements)

Comment: @POW I followed the guide http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2604/fall02/binio.html

Comment: That second `myfile.read` at the page you're linking to is not supposed to be in the same code, it is an alternative. Hence the "// Same effect as above".

Comment: Problem Solved. Thanks a lot POW. The problem was with reading the file twice. I commented the second block where i was reading the file again and it worked. Thanks a lot to refp and Laszlo Papp for editing my post.

Comment: @MajidKhan Ah in the given link its has a `...` in between the examples. It shows two different way to read file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I followed the guide [courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2604/fall02/binio.html](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2604/fall02/binio.html)*

The example shows two different ways to read a file notice a **...**  in  between example.

It also says **`// Same effect as above`**

So just comment out either of the two read call.

```
    fstream myfile("input.txt", ios::in);

    //myfile.read((char *)&map_data,121);

    if(!myfile.read((char *)&map_data,121))
    {
       cout<<"Second error occurred";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm semi surprised that only the first character is missing.  It ought to be missing 121 chars.

```
fstream myfile("input.txt", ios::in);

// you read 121 bytes here...
myfile.read((char *)&map_data,121);

if (!myfile) {
    cout<<"Unable to open the file";
}

// and then do it again here, before you ever look at `map_data`.
if (!myfile.read((char *)&map_data,121)) {
    cout<<"Second error occurred";
}
```

Comment: Thanks cHao. I found the answer. Can you post this? i can't. I was reading the file twice. I commented the second block where i was reading the file again and everything was fine. It wasn't a problem. Sorry my mistake. I followed the guide http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2604/fall02/binio.html.